# XML like file processing in python

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like xml. Here is a snippet

```
<info>
    <fName> Tadele
     <lName> Tedla
      <pNumber> 000-000-000
</info>
<info>
    <fName> Lazarus 
    <lName>
    Tadele  
    <pNumber> 000
    -000
    -000
</info>
```

The *info* tag opens and closes consistently but the others consistently opens but not closes. What I want to do is, extract *fName* and *pNumber* as follows or I want my output to look like the following:

> Tadele  000-000-000
>
> Lazarus  000-000-000

What I have done so far is:

```
# Read file line by line and append to list
filename = 'file.txt' 
appendList = []
with open(filename) as myfile:
    lineList= myfile.readlines()
    for n in range(len(lineList)):
         appendList.append(lineList[n].replace("\n", " ")) # appending lineList to appendList rplacing \n with space 

fNameMatch = [myfName for myfName in appendList if "<fName>"  in myfName ] # search fName and keep it in fNameMatch
pNumberMatch = [mypNumber for mypNumber in appendList if "<pNumber>"  in  mypNumber] # search pNumber and bucket it in pNumberMatch

nameNumMatchedList = [] # a list for storing name and number stripping the tags
for m in range(len(fNameMatch)):
    nameNumMatchedList.append(fNameMatch[m].strip ('<fName>')) # strip <pNumber>
    nameNumMatchedList.append(pNumberMatch[m].strip('<pNumber>')) # stip <pNumber>

joinNameNum= [Name+Num for Name,Num in zip(nameNumMatchedList[::2], nameNumMatchedList[1::2])] # join the first two items in the  nameNumMatchedList
print '\n'.join([str(nameNum) for nameNum in joinNameNum]) # print name and number per line
```

The above code works fine if the unclosed tags and their respective values are in the same line. This happens because I am reading the file a line (readlines()) at a time. I have also tried to pipe the file into BeautifulSoup to add a corresponding closing tag so that I can process the file as a well formed xml but didn't work for me as BeautifulSoup piles the matching closing tags at the end. So my question is:

1. Is it possible to capture the values of the unclosed tags using python even if the values are spreading across multiple line; and get the desired output as indicated above?
2. If not possible, i am also open to suggestion to approach the problem differently so as to get the desired output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "fix" your file before running the code you've already created this way:

```
with open(filename) as myfile:
    lineList= myfile.readlines()
    for ind,line in enumerate(lineList):
        while line.split()[0][0] != '<':
            lineList[ind-1] = lineList[ind-1] + lineList.pop(ind)
            line = lineList[ind]
```

Then continue with your code as before.

The above should get rid of any data sitting on a line by itself and put it on the end of the previous tagged line. Note that you'll get an error on line # 4 above if any of the lines are blank. To get rid of blanks, you can do this prior:

```
while True:
    try:
        lineList.pop(lineList.index(''))
    except:
        break
```

Optionally, if you would like to convert your code to a more valid XML format so you can use XML parsing tools, you could do this (continuing on from the script above):

```
for ind,line in enumerate(lineList):
    tag = line[line.find('<') + 1 : line.find('>')]
    if tag not in ('info','/info'):
        lineList[ind] = lineList[ind] + '</' + tag + '>'
```

Comment: thanks this works well and  many thanks for the option to make a well formed xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works acceptably well, considering such horrible input:

```
import re

intext = """
<info>
    <fName> Tadele
     <lName> Tedla
      <pNumber> 000-000-000
</info>
<info>
    <fName> Lazarus 
    <lName>
    Tadele  
    <pNumber> 000
    -000
    -000
</info>
"""

def decode(s):
    r = re.findall(r"<([^>]*)>([^<]*)", s)
    for pair in r:
        # Clean up data fields
        dta = pair[1].replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
        print pair[0], "   ", dta

def main():
    decode(intext)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Gives:

```
info     
fName     Tadele
lName     Tedla
pNumber     000-000-000
/info     
info     
fName     Lazarus
lName     Tadele
pNumber     000-000-000
/info
```

Depending in `pair[0]`, you can decide what you do with the actual data in `pair[1]`. Ignore `pair[0] = \info`, but you could use `pair[0] = info` to make sure the data is grouped.

Comment: Yes this works well if all of **intext* is in memory; which is OK if the file is not that big. But can we do it without bringing the whole file content into memory at once?

Comment: Generally, you should not accept answers if you have additional questions. You're making it impossible to properly answer you. Here is the code that does what you want: http://pastebin.com/Edx8SCYx

Comment: @Veky will correct  in the future but asked this first before looking the accepted answer. There is 7 mins gap in between and the accepted answer addressed the concern raised here. Should have waited long :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure how foolproof this is but it should work for the majority of your text:

```
>>> re.findall(e, re.sub('>\s*<','><', intext.strip().replace('>\n','>')), re.S|re.M)
[(' Tadele\n     ', ' 000-000-000\n'), (' Lazarus \n    ', ' 000\n    -000\n    -000\n')]
```